# Sage Roots $_GET and $_POST variables

Tags: wordpress, roots-sage

What is the best practice for getting $_POST and $_GET variables to template files? Because I can ofcourse use $_POST and $_GET in each template file. But I might be overlooking something. I cant imagine this is the way to do it.

If it is the best way please comment. If you have a better way of doing this, I am happy to hear you!

Cheers,

Martijn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I am here to answer my own question

**Step 1:** Register your query variable function and hook it up :wink:

```
function add_query_vars( $qvars ) {
$qvars[] = 'var_x';
$qvars[] = 'var_y';
$qvars[] = 'var_z';
return $qvars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', NAMESPACE . '\add_query_vars' );
```

**Step 2:** refresh permalinks

**Step 3:** Retrieve your variables

```
<?php $var_x = get_query_var('var_x ', -1 ); ?>
<?php $var_y = get_query_var('var_y ', -1 ); ?>
<?php $var_z = get_query_var('var_z ', -1 ); ?>
```

Let me know if this is the right way.